# Wordpress: to replace built-in user login after taking data from cookie set by myAuthsite

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, multisite, wordpress-login

I am trying to load user profile of contributor after taking data from cookie set by www.my**Auth**Site.org. 
If username from cookie does not already exist in wp_users table of Wordpress then I am inserting required user data in wp_users table but if username already exist then I want to load the current user dashboard so that he can post new articles on my site, same as he can do when he logs in using http://www.mysiteurl.org/wp-login.php.

but when I am redirecting it to http//www.mysiteurl.org/wp-admin/post-new.php
It is getting redirected to wp-login.php again and it is eventually getting redirected to http://myAuthsite.org (i.e, else part)

below is code I have written in my functions.php file

```
function redirect_login_page(){
$page_viewed = basename( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
global $user;
$temp = getLoggedIn(); // to check if cookie exist by using custom getLoggedIn() 
if( $page_viewed== "wp-login.php" && isset( $temp )  ) {  // if user wants to login and cookie is set 
    $myusername=getLoggedIn();   //get username details from cookie

    // to check if user already exist in wp_users table 
    $response = wp_remote_get( "http://www.mysiteurl.org/demo.php?user=$myusername" );  
    $ext_auth = json_decode( $response['body'], true );
    if( $ext_auth['result']  == 0 ) {  //if cookie user does not already exist  
        /*
        some of my required code
        ......
        */
        $userdata = array(
            'user_email'=> $myuseremail,                                                
            'user_login' => $myusername,
            'user_nicename' => $myusername,
            'user_pass'=> $myuserpassword
        );
        $new_user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ); // A new user has been created with details from cookie
        // Load the new user info
        $user = new WP_User ($new_user_id);
    } else if( $ext_auth['result'] == 1 ) {
        // External user already exist, try to load the user info from the WordPress wp_users table
        $user = new WP_User ($ext_auth['id']);
    }
    $temppassword="password from wp_users table"; // 
    $creds = array();
    $creds['user_login'] = $myusername;
    $creds['user_password'] = $temppassword;
    $creds['remember'] = true;
    $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
    wp_set_current_user($user->ID);
    if ( is_wp_error($user) )
        echo $user->get_error_message();
    //wp_redirect('http//www.mysiteurl.org/wp-admin/profile.php');
    //NOW $user has all details of current user
    // But if I am redirecting it to dashboard, then instead of loading user profile it is getting redirected to wp-login.php 
    exit();
} //eoif
else{  //if cookie is not set redirect to auth to login and set cookie
    wp_redirect('http://www.myAuthsite.org')
}
}
    add_action( 'init','redirect_login_page' );
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using the user id from the external API directly. Can you verify that those user ids are the same? It does not look like you are passing the newly created user id back to the external auth source to have them be in sync, nor is this probably feasible as each system should be able to have its own ids set up.